# scanf error in Ia32 assembly - getting 2 chars, the second is null

Tags: assembly, scanf, x86

While trying to get 2 chars from user(seperately), I encountered the next problem: the first char is received as expected, but the second is always NULL.
the return value of the second scanf is 0, so it means it really didnt receive anything.

this is the code:

```
    addl    $-4, %esp                   
    pushl   %ebx        #input goes to ebx
    pushl   $charInputFormat
    call    scanf
    addl    $8, %esp            
    movl    (%ebx), %ebx


    #get newChar
    addl    $-4, %esp           
    pushl   %esi        #input goes to esi
    pushl   $charInputFormat
    call    scanf
    addl    $8, %esp            
    movl    (%esi), %esi
```

when:

```
charInputFormat: .string " %c"
```

Can someone tell what's the issue? Thank you!

Comment: Care to give an example of what you actually type at the keyboard?

Comment: for instance, a\nb\n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `addl $-4, %esp` is very suspicious. What do you want to do with those? Allocate space for the input? Then you need to pass the address of that location to `scanf`. As it is, `ebx` and `esi` are uninitialized and point who-knows-where (unless you initialized them in code not shown). Maybe `ebx` points into `charInputFormat` by accident and overwrites it before the second `scanf` call.

This code works fine here:

```
.globl main
main:
    subl    $4, %esp            # space for input

    pushl   %esp                # pointer to 1st char
    pushl   $charInputFormat    # pass as argument
    call    scanf
    addl    $8, %esp

    leal    1(%esp), %eax       # pointer to 2nd char
    push    %eax                # pass as argument
    pushl   $charInputFormat
    call    scanf
    addl    $8, %esp

    movb    (%esp), %al         # first input
    movb    1(%esp), %dl        # second input

    push %edx
    push %eax
    push $outputFormat
    call printf

    addl $16, %esp              # restore stack
    ret

.data
charInputFormat: .string " %c"
outputFormat: .string "Got %c and %c\n"
```

Comment: You're right. my mistake was that I figured a new location will be stored in ebx,esi, while I should have pushed locations to the stack. Thank you